# Custom control c# for mark-up aligning controls to others

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

How Would I center my labels and my text boxes I want them like the uwp date time picker.

```
public class DateTimePicker2: ContentView, INotifyPropertyChanged 
{
    public Entry _entry { get; private set; } = new Entry() 
    {
      WidthRequest = 300
    };
    
    public Entry _dayEntry { get; private set; } = new Entry() 
    {
      Placeholder = "00", WidthRequest = 30
    };
    
    public Entry _monthEntry { get; private set; } = new Entry() 
    {
      Placeholder = "00", WidthRequest = 30
    };
    
    public Entry _yearEntry { get; private set; } = new Entry() 
    {
      Placeholder = "00", WidthRequest = 30
    };
    
    public Entry _hourEntry { get; private set; } = new Entry() 
    {
      Placeholder = "00", WidthRequest = 30
    };
    
    public Entry _minsEntry {get;private set; } = new Entry() 
    {
      Placeholder = "00", WidthRequest = 30
    };
    
    private static DateTime ? _defaultDateTime = DateTime.Now;
    
    public DatePicker _datePicker { get; private set; } = new DatePicker() 
    {
      MinimumDate = DateTime.Today, IsVisible = false
    };
    
    public TimePicker _timePicker { get; private set; } = new TimePicker()
    {
      IsVisible = false
    };
    
    public Label _dayLabel { get; private set; } = new Label() 
    {
      Text = "DAY"
    };
    
    public Label _monthLabel { get; private set; } = new Label() 
    {
      Text = "MONTH"
    };
    
    public Label _yearLabel { get; private set; } = new Label() 
    {
      Text = "Year"
    };
    
    public Label _hourLabel { get; private set; } = new Label() 
    {
      Text = "Hour"
    };
    
    public Label  _minLabel { get; private set; } = new Label() 
    {
      Text = "Min"
    };
    
    public Picker _ampmPicker { get; private set; } = new Picker() 
    {
      ItemsSource = new List < string > { "AM", "PM" }
    };
    
    public Picker _twntyFourHourPicker { get; private set; } = new Picker()
    {
      ItemsSource = new List < string > { "12", "24" }
    };

    public DateTimePicker2() 
    {
        BindingContext = this;
        Content = new Frame() 
        {
            BorderColor = Color.Black,
            CornerRadius = 30,
            Padding = new Thickness(10, 10, 10, 10),
            Margin = new Thickness(20),
            Content = new StackLayout 
            {
                Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
                Children = 
                {
                    _dayLabel,
                    _dayEntry,
                    _monthLabel,
                    _monthEntry,
                    _yearLabel,
                    _yearEntry,
                    _hourLabel,
                    _hourEntry,
                    _minLabel,
                    _minsEntry,
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Basically, at present it its showing as such I want the rounded corners only to be the width of the controls and the Labels to be cantered above the text boxes is that possible if it means making text boxes bigger am ok with that,  but as long as the text is centered.

By the way, am using c# for mark-up to render the controls.

[image]

Comment: use `VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center` to center a control vertically within it's container

Comment: what about the border?

Comment: What about it?  If you want two rows of controls aligned vertically and horizontally, use a Grid.

Comment: That didnt work they didnt align properly with that

Comment: And I have no clue how to do a grid in c# for markup @Jason that would suit this purpose

Comment: https://xamgirl.com/grids-xamarin-forms-made-simple/

Comment: She not showing it in c# for markup ! @Jason

Comment: every single example in her article contains both C# **AND** XAML.  And there are numerous other examples of creating a Grid in code available.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60093091/199364. One of the answer given when google `xamarin forms define grid in "c#" code behind`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using **Xamarin.Forms Grid** can make the data more regular.

For more information, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/grid

I wrote a small example for your reference：

Here is background code:

```
Grid grid = new Grid
{
    RowDefinitions =
    {
        new RowDefinition { Height = 25 },
        new RowDefinition { Height = 50 },
    },
    ColumnDefinitions =
    {
        new ColumnDefinition { Width = 65 },
        new ColumnDefinition { Width = 65 },
        new ColumnDefinition { Width = 65 },
        new ColumnDefinition { Width = 65 },
        new ColumnDefinition { Width = 65 }
    }
};
grid.Children.Add(new Label { Text = "Day" }, 0, 0);
grid.Children.Add(new Label { Text = "Month" }, 1, 0);
grid.Children.Add(new Label { Text = "Year" }, 2, 0);
grid.Children.Add(new Label { Text = "Hour" }, 3, 0);
grid.Children.Add(new Label { Text = "Min" }, 4, 0);
grid.Children.Add(new Entry { Placeholder = "00" }, 0, 1);
grid.Children.Add(new Entry { Placeholder = "00" }, 1, 1);
grid.Children.Add(new Entry { Placeholder = "00" }, 2, 1);
grid.Children.Add(new Entry { Placeholder = "00" }, 3, 1);
grid.Children.Add(new Entry { Placeholder = "00" }, 4, 1);

StackLayout stackLayout = new StackLayout
{
    Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
    Children =
    {
       grid
    }
};
Frame defaultFrame = new Frame
{
    Content = stackLayout,
    CornerRadius = 30,
    Margin = new Thickness(20,20,20,20)
};

Content = new StackLayout
{
    Children =
    {
        defaultFrame
    }
};
```

Comment: You will notice above am using c# for markup wendy also with that option i cant seem to name components i need the equalivant c # for markup

Comment: I have updated my code to pure C# code.

Comment: As I was asking others is their anyway to get rid of the underline in the text boxes the border line bottom i mean, and make them one continues line or none at all